# How to check if a variable has all members of an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Lets say I have a canvas that can draw shapes and handle such events as onClick..etc.
Every shape that can be drawn by canvas implements Drawable interface.

```
interface Drawable{
   toPath(): Path2D;
}
```

If a shape supports mouse events it implements SupportsEvents interface.

```
interface SupportsEvents{
   on(eventName, callback);
   trigger(eventName);
}
```

There's an array of all shapes:

```
shapesToDraw: Drawable[] = [];
```

Its Drawable[] because canvas draws all shapes from this array.
But when user clicks canvas detects which shape did user click and triggers its 'onclick' event.
So it should filter the array and leave the shapes that support events (implement SupportsEvents) and how do i do that?

```
shapesToDraw.filter(shape=>shape.hasPoint() && shape implements SupportsEvents)
```

Of course I can check if each `'on'in shape && 'trigger' in shape` but is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see how you could check the interface at run-time, considering that interfaces in Typescript only exist at compile-time. Checking if the members exist sounds like a more "natural" approach to me.

Answer (score 2):

The question of using a runtime check to see whether an object is a particular type has different answers.  TypeScript doesn't give you a magical way to do this (because it doesn't add any runtime capabilities) so you need to write your own. But you can do so in a way that TypeScript understands what you're doing and will narrow types for you:

Let's say you decide that if a `Drawable` has an `on` and a `trigger` key, then it implements `SupportsEvents`.  Here's a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that lets TypeScript know what you're doing:

```
function implementsSupportsEvents(shape: Drawable): shape is Drawable & SupportsEvents {
  return 'on' in shape && 'trigger' in shape
}
```

Now, you can `filter` using this type guard:

```
var shapesSupportingEvents = shapesToDraw.filter(implementsSupportsEvents);
```

and if you look at the type of `shapesSupportingEvents`, you will see that TypeScript infers it as `(Drawable & SupportsEvents)[]`, allowing things like the following to compile:

```
shapesSupportingEvents.forEach(shape => shape.trigger('click'));
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!